# UPDATE SQL Table with Value Added to it's Original Value C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am querying with this code

```
SqlCommand Update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TermsTable SET Doc_ID += @Doc, Freq += @Frq ,Postion += @Pos WHERE Term=@Trm ", GetConnection());

Update.Parameters.Add(@"Doc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (";" + ID.ToString()).ToString();
Update.Parameters.Add(@"Frq", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (";" + PureContent.CountWordinThext(word, PureContent.GetContentPure)).ToString();
Update.Parameters.Add(@"Pos", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =( ";" + PureContent.GetPostionWithinStrin(PureContent.GetContentPure, word)).ToString();
Update.Parameters.Add(@"Trm", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (";" + word.ToLower()).ToString();

Update.ExecuteNonQuery();
Update.Parameters.Clear();
```

To update table with adding new value to it's original value, it worked fine on my SQL machine - otherwise my machine it executed but with no update in my table.

Comment: why you are appending a `";" +` all time?

Comment: If it updated no rows and returned no errors, then nothing matches the `where` clause.

Comment: try surrounding it with a try/catch statement debug your code, so you can see what exception it returns

Comment: @un-lucky because i want to spreat between the original value  and the value that i update it .

Comment: does your column Term  have a semicolon on its data?

Comment: @JCBorlagdan That's what i Actually did , but try and catch did not catch any errors .

Comment: is that necessary in `WHERE Term=@Trm` too

Comment: @un-lucky No it's not necessary to update `term` i use it for checking ..just

Comment: @JCBorlagdan No it has number for ex.  it's Original Value is `911` i want to add new number and sprat between these two (Original - Added ) number with semicolon to store it as `911;123` .

Comment: and that's why it doesn't update any value, you're trying to search for a data which has semi colon in the column Term, do you get what i'm saying? it's like WHERE Term = ";"+"someword";

Comment: @JCBorlagdan yes i got it , but how i can pass `;` as string not as a end to the query

Comment: If you're putting delimited text in a column, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Update.Parameters.Add(@"Trm", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (";" + word.ToLower()).ToString();
```

To

```
Update.Parameters.Add(@"Trm", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = word;
```

Remove the semicolon to search for only the `word` "term" you want and remove the `ToLower` as it is case sensitive.

**EDIT**:

By the way all these `ToString()` are redundant; for example you could change:

```
Update.Parameters.Add(@"Doc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (";" + ID.ToString()).ToString();
```

to

```
Update.Parameters.Add(@"Doc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ";" + ID;
```

Comment: Thank my Mr @Bassem i just miss my attention  to look at that i add ` ;` to `term` thanks

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. Glad to help.